# Google App Engine Locally: ImportError: No module named google.cloud.bigquery

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

As the title says.

So I've added the following to `appengine_config.py` with no luck:

```
# appengine_config.py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

I did a `print sys.path` and verified the lib dir contains google/cloud/bigquery

I can import it if I run python myself:

```
 from google.cloud import bigquery
 print bigquery.__path__
 ['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery']
```

From a Google App Engine end points:

```
import google.cloud;print google.cloud.__path__
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud']
```

Big Query is at that system location. `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/biqguery/` exists.  However if I try the following from app engine end point:

```
 from google.cloud import bigquery

 ImportError: No module named google.cloud.bigquery
```

The file in question includes and that does not appear to help:

```
 from __future__ import absolute_import
```

### Update

I setup a venv and install everything like this: `pip install -t lib/ -r requirements.txt --upgrade`.  From there if I try `import google; print google.__path__` I get:

```
 ['lib/google', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google']
```

I think the second path might be the cause.

I've reviewed the following with no success:

- [Error importing Google Cloud Bigquery api module in python app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40886217/error-importing-google-cloud-bigquery-api-module-in-python-app)
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2366
- [How to import BigQuery in AppEngine for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43085047/how-to-import-bigquery-in-appengine-for-python?rq=1)

Comment: A possible workaround was posted [on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/C5LjgIiJwJY/It6nZKLRCQAJ), is it of any help? Or have you now resolved this issue in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `google-cloud-bigquery` into you app's `lib` dir, that's where the development server is looking at, not on your system's libs. From [Installing a third-party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library):

> 1. Create a directory to store your third-party libraries, such as `lib/`.
>
>    ```
>    mkdir lib
>    ```
> 2. Use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) (version 6 or later) with the `-t <directory>` flag to copy the libraries into the folder you created in the previous
>      step. For example:
>
>    ```
>    pip install -t lib/ <library_name>
>    ```

Comment: Well at first I created a venv and installing my requirements there.  Did not help.  I tried what you just suggested and same error.  From the root of my project I executed your steps.  Honestly I've already tried this but I felt maybe I should try again to be safe.  Inside venv, outside venv.  A hint might be that when deployed on google app engine I am getting the same error.  I can check the sys.path and the first directory listed has the bigquery folder.

Comment: That `/usr/local/lib` path is useless on GAE - only the directories below your app (actually your app's service!) directory end up on GAE.

Comment: Yeah I've moved to using a venv, manually installing the libs in my projects lib dir.  I made progress actually.  bigquery is seen but now I am getting "no suitable implementation" when bigquery imports monotonic.  I'll update my answer with details once I sort that out.  Also running on GAE itself bigquery is still not found.

Comment: Also - don't try to import/check it from a regular python script or shell, but from a GAE app code. GAE apps work differently than standalone python apps - they work combined with supporting code in the GAE infra.